# webpack watch option during multi config

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've created two configs for webpack.

When I'm exporting an array of configs: everything works, instead of watch option. The tasks simply finish (with success).

When I test one configuration exports - watch works fine.

I've tried multiple entry points, and watch worked also fine that time,
but config looked a little messy.

I'll atach my configs, hope for advices, thanks.

```
/* FRONT-END CONFIG */
var frontWebpackConfig = {
  entry: "./src/front/app",

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "public/app.js"
  },

  watch: NODE_ENV == "development",

  watchOptions : {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
  },

  devtool : NODE_ENV == "development" ? "cheap-inline-module-source-map" : null,

  plugins : [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      NODE_ENV : JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)
    })
  ],

  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.js$/,
        loader : 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  }
};


/* BACK-END CONFIG */
var backWebpackConfig = {
  entry: "./src/back/server",

  target : 'node',

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "server.js"
  },

  externals: nodeModules,

  watch: NODE_ENV == "development",

  watchOptions : {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
  },

  devtool : NODE_ENV == "development" ? "cheap-inline-module-source-map" : null,

  plugins : [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      NODE_ENV : JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)
    })
  ],

  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.js$/,
        loader : 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


/* EXPORTS */
module.exports = [frontWebpackConfig, backWebpackConfig]
```

Also, I've cheked this expressions: "NODE_ENV == "development" " value, and tried to set true directly.

**Update:** funny thing, I've just tried to launch with "--watch" option in command line and it worked fine. Any ideas why file config doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`watch` isn't a configuration option in Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html). As you've suggested you need to either pass it on the CLI or call `watch` instead of `run` when using the Node API:

```
compiler.watch({ ...watchOptions }, function(err, stats) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there *is* an option for `watch` in `webpack 1.13.0+`.

But it seems, that in case of several configurations (array of objects) `watch` property should be set to the array to make it work. Eventually `watchOptions` property of the first configuration object would be used.

```
/* FRONT-END CONFIG */
var frontWebpackConfig = {
    entry: "./src/front/app",
    // ...
    watch: NODE_ENV == "development",
    watchOptions : {
        aggregateTimeout: 100,
    },
};

/* BACK-END CONFIG */
var backWebpackConfig = {
    entry: "./src/back/server",
    // ...
};

var configuration = [frontWebpackConfig, backWebpackConfig];
configuration.watch = true;

/* EXPORTS */
module.exports = configuration;
```

`--watch` argument in the command line just sets `watch` property to the array during configuration loading and processing, that's why using CLI argument works as it's expected.